# Sessions are remembered even after system restart. Issue in system or browser?

Tags: php, session, timeout

I guess this problem is not because of my project. I have a login timeout in my project. Say 20 minutes. So if the timeout is encountered, it will redirect to **login/?error=timeout**.

Recently I have observed, if I restart my browser or restart my system, when I try to open my project homepage, it must redirect simply to **login/**. But it redirect with timeout message. And the username is filled from the SESSION variable. I was analyzing my code from line 1 till last and I was not able to find any bug. I observed this same problem with phpMyAdmin too with error message,

**No activity within 7200 seconds.** (I have configured phpMyAdmin timeout as 7200).

What is the reason behind this problem? Previously if I close the browser and reopen it, all the SESSION variables were deleted. But now even after the system restart, it continues to exist. I have observed this problem only in Google Chrome.

**Edit: I am using Chrome Beta version.**

Comment: 2 options: 1 => When you first opened chrome, it opens restored pages last visited. You will automatically redirected to timeout page. 2=> You are using cookies in your projects, cookies still exists although restart system

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL: When I reopen the Chrome, usually it does not asks for restore pages last visited. Only when the system or the browser crashes.

Comment: Ok, what about cookies?

Comment: When Chrome re-opens your page, try a refresh or a hard refresh (usually with Shift, to force a reload). Do you get the same behaviour then?

Comment: I am not creating or using cookies in my project. But phpMyAdmin, does.

Comment: Your problem with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Both my project and phpMyAdmin.